# lookup a word in a file and verify the values for the last 3 occurances

Tags: awk, grep

I am performing a grep for word "percent" in log

```
strings /var/lib/activemq/data/gc.log |grep percent | grep ten
```

which gives me an output

```
<mem type="tenure" free="2188996168" total="2617245696" percent="83" />
```

out of which i need to check the last instances and report

```
CRITICAL is between 10 and 0
WARNING is between 20 and 10
OK status if the usage is over 20
```

for now I did `strings /var/lib/activemq/data/gc.log |grep percent | grep ten |tail -5 | awk {'print $5'}`

and the current output is , I understand this number would vary

```
percent="24"
percent="24"
percent="24"
percent="23"
percent="23"
```

how do I only consider the last 3 values to return an OK, CRITICAL or Warning staus?

Comment: Why in the world do you use `strings` to output the plain-text file? Use `cat` instead. However in your case you don't need even `cat`.

Comment: Is `gc.log` an XML file?  XML is better parsed with an XML parser such as `xmlstarlet`.

Comment: @Kusalananda the gc.log is not in XML format

Comment: Since you are clearly trying to parse XML, maybe the relevant XML-formatted sections could be extracted, and then parsed properly?

Comment: @Kusalananda It is NOT an XML file :)

Comment: Well, ok then, but the stuff you are showing _is_ XML.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with awk.

```
awk -F '"' '/percent/ && /ten/ {if( $(NF-1) > 20 ) {print "OK" } else if ( $(NF-1) < 20 ) {print "WARNING" } else if ( $(NF-1) < 10 ) { print "CRITICAL" }}' /var/lib/activemq/data/gc.log
```

- `-F '"'` double quotes as field separator
- `/percent/ && /ten/` grep lines which has the patterns.
- `( $(NF-1) > 20 )` compare the second last field and print the requires string

Comment: that depends on `percent="83"` being the last argument, which in XML I would not want to depend on ...

Comment: @pLumo agreed... but OP has `$5` in its command so it should be having fixed fields...

Comment: @msp9011, this is returning OK for all the times it find the term percent in the file. I just need to look at the last 3 instances and report an alert based on the threshold i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` only:

```
awk '
/ten/ && /percent/ {
        match($0,"percent=\"([^\"]*)",m)
        if (m[1] < 10) print "CRITICAL"
        else if (m[1] < 20) print "WARNING"
        else print "OK"
}' file  | tail -n3
```

---

But for XML data it is better to use an xml parser:

```
last_percents=$(
    xmlstarlet select -t  -m '//mem[@type="tenure"]' -v '@percent' -n < file \
    | tail -n3
)

for i in $last_percents; do
    if [ $i -lt 10 ]; then echo "CRITICAL"
    elif [ $i -lt 20 ]; then echo "WARNING"
    else echo "OK"
    fi
done
```

Comment: the file is not in XML format.. But he first awk does what I am looking for. is there a way to display the percentage values as well. Currently it outputs only OK 3 times .

Comment: sure,just add `,m[1]` after "OK" in the print statement

Comment: that worked thank you. Iam trying to use this script to setup this in a script that would trigger an alert being Ok, Critial or Warning. exit code 0 for ok and 1 for warning and 2 for critical